# Inno Setup - Use Unshield (libUnshield) from within Inno

Tags: c, inno-setup, installshield, pascalscript

I want to make an installer for an old game that uses InstallShield. The only modern tool (that I know of) that can extract IsCab files is [UnShield](https://github.com/twogood/unshield). Whether Inno will directly call `libUnshield` or run `unshield.exe` doesn't matter. I can barely read C, let alone figure out how to call `libUnshield`, so I tried calling `unshield.exe` during `ssInstall` step, and, even though that *sort of* works, it's not quite all I need it to do.

I need to show the currently installed file in `WizardForm.FilenameLabel` and move the progress gauge accordingly.
On top of that I need to log exactly which files have been installed and delete *only* them during uninstall.

Of course, I would prefer a solution with `libUnshield`, but functionally `unshield.exe` should do the job if it's possible to capture the live output.

Comment: Why do it during the installation time and not ahead of time? Extract everything with UnShield, extract the files from the CAB, and then create an InnoSetup script that uses the results.

Comment: @kichik I've tried that. It doubles the installation time. Takes a while to extract with UnShield, *and then* copy the output to `{app}`.

Comment: I meant do it manually before even creating the installer.

Comment: The game files are still under copyright. I can't provide the game data. The end user should have the CD.